# Deep copy of DataFrame does not remove columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wish to use a subset of the columns of a pd.DataFrame for further analysis.

In this case the first dataframe is called 'data', the deep copy is called 'dual_data'

```
dual_data = data[[column for column in data.columns if 'AbCd' in column]].copy(deep=True)
```

However, afterward I find:

```
data.columns.levels[1] == dual_data.columns.levels[1]
```

gives:
    array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

Which should not be the case as I have just removed 3 out of 4 level 1 columns from the data pd.DataFrame.

I wish to loop through the dual_data.columns.levels[1] but this now loops through columns names that don't even exist in the dual_data pd.DataFrame.

How Do I make a deep copy of a subset of columns and get the correct column names in the .levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encountering the fact that the index is not 'recomputed' (and so the level values re-determined) when doing a selection or a copy.
A workaround to trigger a rebuild of the index, is to create a new index based on the actual values in the index (`data.columns.values`).

Consider this example:

```
In [3]: data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,6), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b']]))

In [4]: data
Out[4]:
          A                   B                   C
          a         b         a         b         a         b
0  0.050503  0.345575  0.293645  0.125889 -0.739698  0.690166
1  1.152101  0.893495 -0.787171 -1.464624 -0.334374 -0.919670

In [5]: data2 = data[[column for column in data.columns if 'A' in column]]

In [6]: data2
Out[6]:
          A
          a         b
0  0.050503  0.345575
1  1.152101  0.893495

In [7]: data2.columns.levels
Out[7]: FrozenList([[u'A', u'B', u'C'], [u'a', u'b']])
```

As you described in your question, the `levels` above still include the original level values. To get 'clean' levels, you can rebuild the index manually and assign it:

```
In [9]: data2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(data2.columns.values)

In [10]: data2
Out[10]:
          A
          a         b
0  0.050503  0.345575
1  1.152101  0.893495

In [11]: data2.columns.levels
Out[11]: FrozenList([[u'A'], [u'a', u'b']])
```

See also https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2770 for some discussion on this issue.

Comment: Worked, great, thanx!!